# How to disable/customize keyboard shortcuts in Excel 365?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, office365

How to disable/customize keyboard shortcuts in Excel 365?

I want to disable Ctrl-D shortcut, which increases probability of sensitive worksheet damage.

Comment: I don't think there is a way for that in excel. You might use autohotkey or something similar.

Comment: VBA Application.OnKey(Key, [Procedure])

Comment: Could you create a vba macro that does nothing and then assign CTRL D to it?

Comment: AFAK there is no method to customize keyboard shortcuts for Excel, but when you record a macro, you can assign a keyboard shortcut to it.